# How do I rearrange an adjacency matrix of an acyclic digraph so its non-zero elements are above the diagonal?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Any graph can be represented by an adjacency matrix. The matrix for an acyclic digraph can be represented as a matrix with all its non-zero elements above the diagonal.

However, if I were to take an arbitrary, acyclic digraph I am unlikely to get the adjacency matrix in this form (unless I am lucky). I would generally need to re-label the nodes to achieve this.

My question is: given an adjacency matrix for an acyclic digraph, which algorithm rearranges it so that all the non-zero elements are above the diagonal?

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort the vertices so that whenever there is an edge $i \to j$, $i$ comes before $j$.  One way to do that is to count the number of vertices reachable from each vertex, and sort in decreasing order of that.  If $A$ is the original adjacency matrix ($n \times n$), then $j$ is reachable from $i$ iff $((I+A)^{k})_{ij} > 0$ where $k \ge n-1$.  So compute $I+A$, square it
$\lceil \log_2(n-1) \rceil$ times, and count the number of nonzero entries in each row.

Comment: @PHenry For a practical approach, use [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: Thanks for your speedy replies but I don't think it moves me forward. dtldarek: this makes sense but doesn't really answer my question about what operation to perform on the matrix itself. @Robert Israel: I followed your instructions but am none the wiser. I took a 13x13 matrix that represents a graph in Sedgewick's "Algorithms" (as in this blog [link](http://javaagile.blogspot.co.uk/2016_04_01_archive.html) ), added the identity matrix, squared it 4 times (because n = 13) and counted the non-zero elements per row and got [9, 1, 11, 3, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 4, 1, 2, 1]. Now what?

Comment: So you want to have vertex #3 first, because it has the largest sum, #1 second, etc.  Rearrange the rows and columns in that order.